# Ng app with Proxy Config - Why ng serve not run Proxy file

Tags: angular

I add proxy config JSON file , but it's not work
I don't see the NPM Proxy Logs ("proxy rewrite rule create...") in the run 'ng serve'
I think that maybe because the my  "`Proxy config"` file is in gray ?!
Does anyone know of such a problem?

proxy config file

[image]

[image]

The my file is gray:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I made a mistake in the Path and put Http instead of https.
Take a look, maybe you too have a mistake in the Path